# Is it possible to isolate db table from read operations in transaction?

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, transactions

I'm writing Java app(Spring Data/Hibernate/JPA), which should work with MySQL DB.
I have a simple task, which should be atomic:
1. Retrieve first item from database
2. Bind this item to current user(UPDATE item SET user_id=current_user_id WHERE id=id)

I've put 500ms pause between these two steps to test it against concurrency and run it in transaction. Transaction exists, at least it rollbacks if I throw exception in this code.
But atomicity doesn't work as I want it to, with this 500ms pause I get the following situation:

1. **user1** starts transaction
2. **user1** retrieves first item - **item1**
3. **user2** starts transaction
4. **user2** retrieves first item - **item1**
5. **user1** updates **item1**
6. **user1** commits transaction
7. **user2** updates **item1**
8. **user2** commits transaction

Is there a way to isolate table from user2's read/write queries while user1 is in transaction? It should be DB level transaction to allow 2 instances of the app on different servers.

Answer (score 1):

You shoiuld either use `SELECT FOR UPDATE` to lock it or introduce versions on hibernate level (Read about optimistic lock [here](http://squirrel.pl/blog/2012/11/02/version-based-optimistic-concurrency-control-in-jpahibernate/)).

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of Hibernates Pessimistic lock which take lock on the row you are fetching until transaction get completed.
Please refer to the following link.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html

You can make use of **LockMode.UPGRADE** which will restrict user2 if he tries to update the data.